# osm2pgsql Error: operator class "gist_geometry_ops" does not exist for access method "gist"

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, postgresql, osm2pgsql

When using `osm2pgsql` to import `massachusetts-latest.osm.bz2` into PostGIS 2.0.1 database `osm` (running on PostgreSQL 9.1 on an Ubuntu 12.04), I get the error `failed: ERROR:  operator class "gist_geometry_ops" does not exist for access method "gist"`.

I have ran the enabler `.sql` scripts including `legacy.sql`. Truncating the tables and reimporting does not help. Any idea what is causing this error?

**Command**

`osm2pgsql massachusetts-latest.osm.osm.bz2 -d osm -U postgres -P 5432 --hstore -W`

**Output:**

```
Reading in file: massachusetts-latest.osm.bz2
Processing: Node(23054k) Way(2370k) Relation(5058)  parse time: 300s

Node stats: total(23054254), max(2147478725)
Way stats: total(2370244), max(215072011)
Relation stats: total(5058), max(2855687)

Writing way (2370k)

Writing relation (5058)
Committing transaction for planet_osm_point
Sorting data and creating indexes for planet_osm_point
Committing transaction for planet_osm_line
Committing transaction for planet_osm_roads
Sorting data and creating indexes for planet_osm_line
Committing transaction for planet_osm_polygon
Sorting data and creating indexes for planet_osm_roads
Sorting data and creating indexes for planet_osm_polygon
CREATE INDEX planet_osm_roads_index ON planet_osm_roads USING GIST (way GIST_GEOMETRY_OPS) TABLESPACE pg_default;
 failed: ERROR:  operator class "gist_geometry_ops" does not exist for access method "gist"

Error occurred, cleaning up
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit2**: Over at [BostonGIS, Regina Obe responded](http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=loading_osm_postgis) to a user with this error as follows--

> I think that error happens if you already loaded the data or parts of
>   it. you might want to try truncating your table or if loading multiple
>   files, make sure areas don't overlap

**Edit1**: Did you see [this thread](http://forum.openstreetmap.org/viewtopic.php?pid=293271) at openstreetmap.org, which seems to be a similar issue, complete with a solution?

---

`GIST` is used to create spatial indices, and it's an integral function in PostGIS.

Are you *very* sure the PostGIS extension is setup on that schema instance? Just because one schema in a PostGRESql database has the PostGIS extension, it doesn't mean they all do. Try running this query to get the PostGIS version integrated into your schema (basically proving its really functioning):

`SELECT PostGIS_full_version();`

If that query returns a valid result, I'm baffled. But it seems like it could be an easy mistake---creating a schema without basing it on the PostGIS template. I apologize if I'm just wasting your time!

Answer (score 4):

There’s a thorough explanation in the [PostGIS FAQ](http://postgis.net/docs/PostGIS_FAQ.html#legacy_faq_gist):

> In PostGIS 2, the default geometry operator class gist_geometry_ops was changed to gist_geometry_ops_2d and the gist_geometry_ops was completely removed.

Simply remove the gist_geometry_ops statement, changing this:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_my_table_geom ON my_table USING gist(geom gist_geometry_ops);
```

To this:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_my_table_geom ON my_table USING gist(geom);
```